# Gitlab CI, Matlab - Unable to read xls through Matlab while fired from Gitlab CI

Tags: excel, matlab, gitlab

I am trying to fire following command through gitlab-ci.yml :

C:\MATLABR2016b\bin\matlab.exe -wait -r "try; clear; [~,text,~]=xlsread('Model\TestCase1.xlsx'); catch e; disp('Error building model  '); disp(e.message); exit(1); end;  disp('PASS'); exit(0);" -logfile log.txt exit;'

Matlab starts as a background process. Creates a log, but following error is encountered:

"Error building model
Calling error, exception dispatching:
Source: Microsoft Excel
Explanation: The file 'C: \ gitlab \ test \ SampleTestProject \ TestFolder \ Model \ Testcase1.xlsx' can not be accessed. One of the following reasons is considered.

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• A workbook with the same name as the workbook you are trying to save is currently open.
Help file: xlmain11.chm
Help context ID: 0"

Tried restarting the pc, checking if the file is already open, endind excel processes in task manager. But nothing works!

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I was running gitlab runner  using command "git-runner.exe start" due to which it is starting in non-Desktop interacting mode.
To resolve the issue, started it as "git-runner.exe run" and the issue resolved